# How to cut/crop/trim a video in respect with time or percentage and save output in different file

Tags: c#, .net, video, wrapper, video-capture

Is there any tutorial or a c# library which which help me to accomplish the following

1. Chose a file to edit
2. Ask user to select cut/crop/trim method :- by time or by percentage
3. cut/crop/trim the video by time or percentage as chosen ( say I wish
   to reduce a 5 minute video to 4 minute video, or reduce the video by
   80%)
4. Save the video as requested in required path

now steps 1) and 4) I have implemented but could not find a good c# library to accomplish 3) and 4)

I looked up the `ffmpeg` library but could not find a good C# wrapper to accomplish the requirements.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

ffmpeg is a very powerful application and I have used it many times, even from C#. You don't need a C# wrapper library. All you have to do is execute the ffmpeg commands from C# using:

`System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(string fileName, string arguments);`

Or use `System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo` to redirect standard output if you need to.

This article explains how to use `System.Diagnostics` to execute synchronous and asynchronous commands, etc.
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/Execute_Command_in_CSharp.aspx

Here's a simple example of how to cut a video file down to its first 4 minutes using ffmpeg from C#.

```
using System.Diagnostics
Process.Start("ffmpeg.exe",
              "-sameq -t 240 -i InputVideoFile.avi OutputVideoFile.avi");
```

Here's a SO example of how to use `System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo`
[C# and FFmpeg preferably without shell commands?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1707516/c-and-ffmpeg-preferably-without-shell-commands#1733516)

There are lots of online resources that explain all of ffmpeg's features and how to use them, just search.

Comment: Could you please provide a sample code how to execute ffmpeg in c#

Comment: Hey is there anyway to jump the first 30 seconds before cropping the 4 minutes out?

Comment: Use the `-ss` parameter and specify an offset time in HH:MM:SS.ms format.  For example: `ffmpeg -ss 00:00:50.0 -t 240 -sameq -i InputVideoFile.avi OutputVideoFile.avi`

Comment: I get the following error: 
Option 'sameq' was removed. If you are looking for an option to preserve the qua
lity (which is not what -sameq was for), use -qscale 0 or an equivalent quality
factor option.
Failed to set value '1' for option 'sameq': Invalid argument
Error parsing global options: Invalid argument