# Allow users to upload video to website

Tags: asp.net, video, upload

need the following list to work, anyone know what service best to use to do it?

- Site members can upload videos from website site via API
- Receive embed code immediately & embedded in the site
  *Can control approved/unapproved - Can be marked as inappropriate - this is via kentico site
- Check file type and Limit video to 30 seconds  - this should be done before the upload
- Video can be automatically watermarked with brand logo

I tried Vzaar but there support was terrible and could not get it to work.
YouTube - can branding be done there?  Another issue is that the video is "saved" on the users account (user that uploaded) and can be added to my Chanel.  this is NOT enough control over video.

Site is asp.net.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented this, but only works for mp4 videos. let the user upload the video onto your server. Embed it on to your website using Video tag in HTML5. for Water marking your video check out https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/3ca2162e-a374-415d-a430-59ad9e9135ab/digital-signature-on-video?forum=windowsdirectshowdevelopment

for editing video [How to cut/crop/trim a video in respect with time or percentage and save output in different file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041910/how-to-cut-crop-trim-a-video-in-respect-with-time-or-percentage-and-save-output)

```
       <video width="320" height="240" controls>      
           <source src='give path of file here' type="video/mp4">
             //Text you want to display if html5 is not supported
          Your browser does not support the video.
            </video>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  So you host all your videos?  is that not an issue?

Comment: In my cast the no of videos that will be uploaded is minimal because im allowing youtube and vimeo video embedding. uploading videos is the final option.